# Get array in other method in the same class in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, oop, 2d

I have been looking for an answer on here but i couldn't find any, but anyway my question is how to get an array in a method that has been declared and initialised in an other method but in the same class. I'll make it a bit more clear by demonstrating what i want to achieve and what i have tried so far.

Javascript:

```
class SomeClass {
   method1() {
      var array = new array();
      //its actually a 2d array and it is being initialised here but for simplicity this isn't 
      //necessary in the example.
   }

   method2() {
   // --> Here i want to access the array and it's contents.

   //I have tried this:
   this.array;
   //and 
   array;
   }
}
```

but i got "cannot ready property of undefined" when i tried this.array;

Comment: Not advisable to use a class without a constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare the array as an element of the Class, not inside a method, for that, you can use a constructor.

In this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes) you can see more information.

Here is an example:

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor(someValue) {
    // Initialize array or any other atribute
    this.arr = new Array(someValue);
  }
  
   method1() {
      console.log(this.arr);
   }

   method2() {
     console.log(this.arr);
   }
}

var instance = new SomeClass('data');
instance.method1();
instance.method2();
```

Answer (score 1):

The array which is declared in `method1` will only be available in that function. There is no way to access local variables of a function in some other function.

The solution could be to use the array as property of instance of class

```js
class SomeClass {
   constructor(){
    this.array = []
   }
   method1() {
      console.log(this.array);
   }
   method2() {
      console.log(this.array)
   }
}

const obj = new SomeClass();
obj.method1();
obj.method2();
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so you are making a major mistake, Your concepts of OOP are at stake.
To access array as a property/ instance of a class , You need to declare a constructor it within the class. Somewhat like this

```
  class SomeClass {
     constructor(){
         this.array = new Array();
     }
     yourMethod1(){
        console.log(this.array); /// You cann access it here and manipulate
     }
     yourMethod2(){
        console.log(this.array); // You can accesss here too and do the same
    }
 }
```

Later on you can create an instance of your class like this and access the methods and do whatsoever

```
  let a = new SomeClass();
  a.yourMethod1();
  a.yourMethod2();
```